# Adding a suffix that includes superscript text to axis text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have my x-axis show the scale with an added "m<sup>2</sup>" at the end of each axis text using the `scales::label_number()` function. Reproducible code:

```
tibble(x = 1:10, y = 1:10) |> 
ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
scale_x_continuous(label = scales::label_number(suffix = "m^2"))
```

which gives me "5m^2" (for example) on the x-axis, whereas I want it to show "5m<sup>2</sup>". It seems the usual suspects of `bquote()` and `expression()` do not work with the `scales::label_number()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use unicode for ^2: "m\u00B2" or m^2: "\u33A1"

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(x = 1:10, y = 1:10) |>  
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +  
  scale_x_continuous(label = scales::label_number(suffix = "m\u00B2"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I did not realise the ^2 was part of unicode :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Using `scales::label_parse` you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    label = ~ scales::label_parse()(
      paste0(scales::label_number()(.x), "*m^2"))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The above code seems to fail when the x-axis values are above 1000. This is because `label_number()` puts a gap between the "1" and "000". I found replacing the `paste0(scales::label_number()(.x), "*m^2")` with `paste0(.x, "*m^2")` overcomes this issue.

Comment: @FreddieJ.Heather. The code does not fail. `label_number` uses a space as grouping mark. And as you desired `label_number` ... (;